# How to Use Mongoid on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ubuntu-11.04

I've been trying to use Mongoid with Rails on Ubuntu. I have installed mongoDB via apt-get. But when I try to run the rails server, I get this error:

> /home/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@mysite/gems/mongo-1.3.1/lib/mongo/connection.rb:518:in
>   `connect': Failed to connect to a
>   master node at localhost:27017
>   (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)

I am just new to using Mongoid, any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Piotr says you need to start the Mongo DB server. If you want to quickly test this, run `mongod` from a shell.

Comment: I've tried using mongod, but I got this: exception in initAndListen std::exception: dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist, terminating

Comment: According to the docs you need to create this directory manually. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Unix .

Answer (score 0):

You need to start MongoDB server. I don't know exactly how to manage services in Ubuntu, but somewhere in /etc/rc.d or /etc/init.d you should have the mongodb script, run it with 'start' argument. I think the default configuration should do for your setup, but check if you have config/mongoid.yml in your Rails app. It should contain something like:

```
development:
  host: localhost
  database: app_development

test:
  host: localhost
  database: app_test

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
[...]
```